# Find function in simple html dom

Tags: php, dom, curl, simple-html-dom

Hello every one i am creating a script which fetch data from webstie and store in database i am using simple html dom but one problem i have face serious and i am stuck in it i need your help please. when i am finding any tag in most pages tag is exists and in some there is no tag so it's give an error call to member function in a non object.

```
$imageSrc = $html->find('div.show-summary table tr td a img',0)->src;
```

In above code i am find image scr value in most pages there are no image tag and anchor tag in td so how can i handle it please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$imageSrc = $html->find(div.show-summary,table,tr,td,a,img)->src;` seperating with comma?

Comment: no bro comma not working i am making hierarchy like <div class="show-summary"> <table><tr><td><a><img src="adsfsdf.png" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image does not exist in a page then.. it does not exist. There is nothing that can be done about that.

Because the image sometimes does not exist you need to check if it was found, before grabbing `src`:

```
$image = $html->find('div.show-summary table tr td a img',0);
if ($image === null) {
    die('No image was found; cannot read src');
} else {
    echo $image->src;
}
```